# PIE.htc - location is correct but still no CSS3 effects in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I have a div.outer that wraps my content, and has a gradient background. I am able to see PIE.htc being loaded (its in the root where index.html is), however no CSS3 effects are taking place.

```
.outer{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
      background: #063A5F; /*fallback for non-CSS3 browsers*/
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#063A5F) to(#063A5F)); /*old webkit*/
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4189CC, #063A5F); /*newer webkit*/
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4189CC, #063A5F); /*old gecko*/
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4189CC, #063A5F); /*opera 11.10+*/
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #063A5F, #4189CC);
   -pie-background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #063A5F, #4189CC); /*ie 6-9 via PIE*/
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

}

Current site is [available here](http://www.edpacheco.com/)

I have tried the z-index issue but perhaps I've done it wrong :)

Also am having issues with border-radius not being applied to my anchor tags.

```
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading PIE.htc into your root directory and / or including the absolute URL to the file in your CSS.

So if you put it in your root directory then the CSS would look like this:

```
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url("http://yourdomain.com/PIE.htc");
}
```

Hope that helps!

PIE is kinda goosey that way.

Comment: I've made this adjustment, and unfortunately still no CSS3 goodness in IE. I did copy and paste the address registered in IE's dev tools into a new window. It indeed is correct as [link](http://www.edpacheco.com/PIE.htc)demonstrated here[/link] . Thanks for the suggestion, Cynthia.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed with the addition of two lines to .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule /PIE.htc$ PIE.htc [L]
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

After viewing the file, I quickly noticed the (joomla) site was using mod rewrites. Many joomla sites take advantage of plugins that generate Search Engine Friendly (SEF) URLs. I simply added the above two lines to the bottom of my .htaccess file and cleared my cache - Problem solved.